# How to fetch all orders excluding very first order of each customer in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here's my `orders` table:

[image]

I want to select all orders excluding very first order of each customer (if customer has placed multiple orders).

So if a customer e.g. 215 has total 8 orders, then I will select his all last 7 orders excluding his very first order 70000 which was placed on 10 July 2017.

But if a customer e.g. 219 had placed only one order 70007, it must be selected by the query.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an anti-join approach:

```
SELECT o1.order_id, o1.customer_id, o1.order_date, o1.order_value
FROM orders o1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS min_order_date, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customer_id
) o2
    ON o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id AND
       o1.order_date = o2.min_order_date
WHERE
    o2.customer_site = 1 AND
    (o2.customer_id IS NULL OR
    o2.cnt = 1);
```

The idea here is to try to match each record in `orders` to a record in the subquery, which contains only first order records, for each customer.  If we *can't* find a match, then such an order record cannot be the first.

Comment: your query didn't work as I mentioned in my post. Your query misses customer 2019 who has just one order. I specifically wrote that such customers must include in the result set.

Comment: @user3779493 Sorry I missed that edge case.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Tim, I have actually one more column called `customer_site` which is either equal to 1 or 2. I want to fetch orders from only customer_site = 1. How to modify above query?

Comment: I already myself did before you updated your answer. But my approach was different. `o1.customer_site = 1 AND (o2.bp_customer_id IS NULL OR...` And no need to use `WHERE customer_site = 1` in second table o2.

Comment: It is so complex. But my solution is easy to understand.

Comment: @user3779493 Actually, you should leave in the restriction `WHERE customer_site = 1` in the outer query, because it will still improve performance.

Comment: OK, right. As you explained - `The idea here is to try to match each record in orders to a record in the subquery, which contains only first order records, for each customer. If we can't find a match, then such an order record cannot be the first.` So is this the reason you used the condition `o2.customer_id IS NULL`. Because the very first order rows will not match to the subquery and we will left with all other records in which customer_id is NULL.

Comment: @user1863229 one more mistake by you. We can't use customer_site in subquery as it skips hundreds of results in my result set.

Comment: Well, you never even showed us sample data which explains your actual problem.  What I wrote is resonable based on what you did show.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select order_id,customer_id,order_date,order_Value
from tablename
group by order_id,customer_id,order_date,order_Value
having count(order_id)=1
union all
select order_id,customer_id,order_date,order_Value
from tablename a where order_date not in (select min(order_date) from tablename b
where a.customer_id=b.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Dear @Tim Biegeleisen, your answer almost done. just add `HAVING COUNT(customer_id)>1`
So the query is below:

```
SELECT o1.order_id, o1.customer_id, o1.order_date, o1.order_value
FROM orders o1 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS min_order_date
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY customer_id
  HAVING COUNT(customer_id)>1
) o2
ON o1.customer_id = o2.customer_id AND
   o1.order_date = o2.min_order_date
WHERE
o2.customer_id IS NULL;
```